# How would one implement a queue if the elements that are to be placed on the queue are arbitrary length strings

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, queue

I don't know how to answer it, anybody help me?

How would one implement a queue if the elements that are to be placed
on the queue are arbitrary length strings? How long does it take to
enqueue a string?

Comment: Usually your programming language would abstract the details away from you (unless you're using something like C or C++, there you would need raw or smart pointers

Comment: Oh yeah, pointers, but how to decide how long

Comment: You have too few pointers. Think more pointers. Just keep adding pointers until everything starts making sense. I'm sort of joking as I don't really want to be too helpful to a question that shows no attempt at solving the problem (sorry), but, at the same time, I'm totally serious.

Comment: If your machine architecture is 64 bit, all pointers will typically have a size of 8 bytes. With just 8 bytes, you can reference more memory addresses than you will ever need.

Comment: @Dukeling "Just keep adding pointers until everything starts making sense." That recursion terminates immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the programming language used. In more high level languages, you can abstract away the details and just implement the queue as a queue of pointers or object references to strings. In that way, every reference use the same space. Now you can look more into how strings of dynamic size can be stored and managed.

If your question really is about how to store the objects on the queue and not just references to them, you can implement the queue in a way such that beside storing each element, it also stores the size of that element. In that way, you can dequeue an element by returning the front element of size `x` bytes and move all but the front element `x` bytes forward in the queue. You will also have to move the back pointer `x` bytes forward.